# How to convert Q_ENUM to QString for QT > 5.11 most efficient way?

Tags: qt, qt5, qstring, qmetaobject

I read several advices how to get an actual `QString` from a `Q_ENUM` value.

Below are 3 possible ways, I came up with, that are compilable constructs in QT5.11.1

What of them should one prefer and why?

```
void MainWindow::setErrorText(QCanBusDevice::CanBusError error)
{
    QString errorString;
    QDebug(&errorString) << error;
    ui->statusBar->showMessage("Error occured: " + errorString);

    // QT4 ?
    const QMetaObject& mo = QCanBusDevice::staticMetaObject;
    QMetaEnum me = mo.enumerator(mo.indexOfEnumerator("CanBusError"));
    QString errorStr(me.valueToKey(QCanBusDevice::UnconnectedState));
    ui->statusBar->showMessage("Error occured: " + errorStr);

   // From QT5?
   QString errorS(QMetaEnum::fromType<QCanBusDevice::CanBusError>().valueToKey(error));
   ui->statusBar->showMessage("Error occured: " + errorS);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`QDebug` should be used for logging and debugging. `QDebug` constructs a `QTextStream` and is quite expensive for what you're trying to do.

Using `QMetaEnum` is proper. You shouldn't be doing string concatenation the way you do, use `tr` for user visible strings, or `QStringLiteral` instead of `tr` elsewhere:

```
const auto errStr = QMetaEnum::fromType<QCanBusDevice::CanBusError>().valueToKey(error);
ui->statusBar->showMessage(tr("Error occured: %1").arg(errStr));
```

Answer (score 4):

Another, more elegant way, is by using QVariant's toString() method:

```
QString errStr = QVariant::fromValue(error).toString();
ui->statusBar->showMessage("Error occured: " + errStr);
```